# How to get DIgSILENT Simulation Language (DSL) pic of the template

Tags: power, windturbine

I am trying to change the template's inner model by using DSL. For example DFIG WT template [image: Template of DFIG], I got from DIgSILENT left-hand menu and its DSL are found from google [image: pic]. But I am not able to find DSL pic in DIgSILENT software. How can I get it? I am using the 2015 model.